# iCloud Photo Library on Macbook Pro, where?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, photos, ios, macos

I have iCloud Photo Library enabled on both iPhone 5S (IOS 8.02) and Macbook Pro (Yosemite)

iPhone settings for iCloud (Photo Library) reports that I have 3 photos in iCloud
(gallery only shows 1 photo (?), but otherwise it seems to sync to icloud fine when taking a new picture)

Where are these photos located excactly (icloud), and **how can I see/use them on my Macbook?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iCloud Photo Library is available starting 2015 on OS X

Until now, you have the chance to

- sync between iOS devices running both iOS 8 and have Photo Library activated.
- activate Photo stream and see your photos in iPhoto

**iCloud Photo Library is still Beta**, and will come to the **Mac in 2015**, and to the **icloud.com as well**.

Comment: Hm ok. I've been waiting and waiting ;) They should not launch an unfinished/useless but "available" function

Answer (score 0):

As for now, the only way to access iCloud Photo Library on a non-iOS device is https://beta.icloud.com/.

Comment: Actually, also on just icloud.com. But we're getting closer! :)